# quantmod plotting csv data

Tags: r, quantmod

I am starting to use R for a data analysis project in my university elective.

The goal is to analyze Ethereum prices related to EUR, I have a .CSV file with all the data and I imported it in R, but when I want to plot the data it shows me this

> Error in try.xts(x, error = "chartSeries requires an xtsible object") : 
>     chartSeries requires an xtsible object

I have named the file spy.csv and put it in my rstudio data folder, but I have no idea how to plot the graph and start analyzing.

```
library(quantmod)

candleChart(spy,multi.col=TRUE,theme='white')
```

Comment: Error suggests your object is not an xts which you need for plotting. Check class(spy). If it's not an xts, make one.

Comment: How to do that? I just started using R-studio I have no idea how this works.

Comment: Suggest you check out the documentation for xts. ?xts

Comment: R and Rstudio are independent pieces of software. Your issue is an R specific issue (and R packages), so is not related to Rstudio, the IDE that you are using.